# Check to see if a variable content has string or not

Tags: java

How can I check if a variable's content is a string or not?

Actually I have a requirement that I need to check json values for being a string or not.

```
String str = "{\"a\":1,\"b\":\"2\",\"c\":\"3\"}";
JSONParser content_parser = new JSONParser();
Object objMessage_Content = content_parser.parse(str);

JSONObject jsonObjectMessage_Content = (JSONObject) objMessage_Content;

jsonObjectMessage_Content.get("a");
```

The above line returns an Object but I need to convert it into string.
If I get a Long value from json how can i convert it into string?

I need to check for `null` value too.

Comment: you can use `instanceof`

Comment: Which JSON library is this?

Comment: org.json.simple.JSONObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `instanceof` operator to check if an Object is an instance of a particular type.

```
Object content = jsonObjectMessage_Content.get("a");
if (content instanceof String) {
    String string = (String) content;
    // Do something ...
} else {
    // Not a String
}
```

If you also want other things to be converted to Strings, like your later updates to your question suggest, you can use the `toString()` method on an Object:

```
Object content = jsonObjectMessage_Content.get("a");
if (content == null) {
    // No content
} else {
    String string = object.toString();
    // Do something with the String. It's a String now, regardless
    // of whether it was a String, Integer, Long, etc. before
}
```